# auto slideshow on javascript

Tags: javascript, slideshow, autoplay

Need help on auto slide show on this script:

```
NewImg = new Array (
"images/Pic03.png",
"images/Pic01.jpg",
"images/Pic02.jpg"
);

var random_display = 0;
var ImgNum = 0;
var ImgLength = NewImg.length - 1;
var totalImages = NewImage.l
//Time delay between Slides in milliseconds
var delay = 1500;
var lock = true;
var run;

function chgImg(direction) {
if (document.images) {
ImgNum = ImgNum + direction;
if (ImgNum > ImgLength) {
ImgNum = 0;
}
if (ImgNum < 0) {
ImgNum = ImgLength;
}

document.slideshow.src = NewImg[ImgNum];
   }
}
```

my next and back button are okay but the slideshow is not playing automatically.

Comment: That's because you haven't included any code to automatically play the slide show

Comment: Use modulo to stay in range : ++ImgNum % ImgLength

Comment: And what is document.slideshow ??? Unless it's a new feature i don't know about, it doesn't exist and is a bad practice.